# Showing Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined error

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I was running a jest test and got the error.it is logged in cli [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06qJv.png).I am providing the service module i am testing.

````
  public async buildCitationMatrix(user: any, { auditId }: CitationMatrixBuildRequest): Promise<any> {
    const transaction = await sequelize.transaction()
    try {
      await sequelizeQuery(CitationMatrixQueries.clearCitationMatrix(), {
        bind: { auditId },
        transaction,
        type: 'DELETE'
      }, user)

      const referenceList: IReferenceWithFileInfo[] = await sequelizeQuery(CitationMatrixQueries.getReferencesByAuditId(), {
        bind: { auditId },
        type: 'SELECT'
      }, user)
      const nplList: IReferenceWithFileInfo[] = await sequelizeQuery(CitationMatrixQueries.getNplByAuditId(), {
        bind: { auditId },
        type: 'SELECT'
      }, user)

      const famListRes: any[] = await sequelizeQuery(CitationMatrixQueries.getIdsFamilyMembersByAuditId(), {
        bind: { auditId },
        type: 'SELECT'
      }, user)
      const familyMemberList = famListRes.map((e: any) => e.member_no)

      // get max ids date for supplemental cases; if not found, uses a very old date
      const maxIdsDateRes: any[] = await sequelizeQuery(CitationMatrixQueries.getMaxIdsDate(), {
        bind: { auditId },
        type: 'SELECT'
      }, user)
      if (!maxIdsDateRes.length) {
        log('No latest IDS file found / not a supplemental IDS. Will build citation matrix on full IDS')
      }
      const maxIdsDateString = get(maxIdsDateRes, '0.max_ids_date', null)
      const maxIdsDate = moment(maxIdsDateString).isValid() ? moment(maxIdsDateString) : null

      const refEntries = this.generateCitationMatrixEntries(auditId, familyMemberList, referenceList, 'ref_no', maxIdsDate)
      const nplEntries = this.generateCitationMatrixEntries(auditId, familyMemberList, nplList, 'npl_text', maxIdsDate)

      const citationMatrix = [...nplEntries, ...refEntries]
      const query = this.generateBulkCreateQuery(citationMatrix)

      const result = await sequelizeQuery(query, {
        bind: {},
        transaction,
      }, user)

      transaction.commit()
      log('citation matrix build', result)
      return 'Citation matrix build successful'
    } catch (err) {
      log('Error(BuildCitationMatrix):', err)
      transaction.rollback()
      throw new Error(err)
    }
    return 'Success'
  }```

kindly help me


I tried this jest->
````

it('buildCitationMatrix: should build the citation matrix successfully', async () => {
// Mock the necessary dependencies and data
const user = {}; // Mock the 'user' object as needed
const auditId = 123; // Mock the 'auditId' as needed
const referenceList: never[] = []; // Mock the referenceList data as needed
const nplList: never[] = []; // Mock the nplList data as needed
const famListRes: never[] = []; // Mock the famListRes data as needed
const maxIdsDateString = '2023-08-25'; // Mock the maxIdsDateString as needed

```
// Mock the database queries
sequelizeQueryStub.onCall(0).resolves(); // Mock the clearCitationMatrix query
sequelizeQueryStub.onCall(1).resolves(referenceList); // Mock the getReferencesByAuditId query
sequelizeQueryStub.onCall(2).resolves(nplList); // Mock the getNplByAuditId query
sequelizeQueryStub.onCall(3).resolves(famListRes); // Mock the getIdsFamilyMembersByAuditId query
sequelizeQueryStub.onCall(4).resolves([{ max_ids_date: maxIdsDateString }]); // Mock the getMaxIdsDate query
sequelizeQueryStub.onCall(5).resolves(); // Mock the generateBulkCreateQuery result


try {
  const result = await citationMatrixService.buildCitationMatrix(user, { auditId });

  expect(result).to.equal('Citation matrix build successful');
} finally {
  sequelizeQueryStub.reset();
}
```

})